# C++: new empty project (how to create it, add main method and print "Hello, world")?

Tags: c++

Well, my program doesn't execute what I want it to. 
A project from the scratch.
Visual Studio 2010.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why the program doesn't print "Hello, world"? And why it doesn't react to the breakpoint?
What shall I do to get what I want?

1. I create a new project.
2. I unmark Precompiled header and mark Empty [project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!133&authkey=!AE9hR4-y4OtqC2c).
3. I add a new item as a cpp file.
4. I type my main [method](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!136&authkey=!AFLOttZldVnfjas). And get an error. LNK1120: unresolved externals. As far as I can understand from googling, this mean that the compiler sees that I use a main method but somehow it doesn't know in which file this method is.
5. I click the right button on my project and add the very file I have just created.
6. I exit VS. And launch it again. It starts compiling but the result is just a flash of black screen.
7. I add a new breakpoint. Just in the middle of the module. The program doesn't react to it at all. So, it just ends.

LATER ADDED:

Thank you all who tried to help.
After flushing the cout Hello, world works.

But! I can't proceed.

Please, have a look at the code.
I replaced "Hello, world" with another piece of code.
But it starts telling me off because of ';'.
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
Is it a strange behaviour of the compiler or I'm goofy?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void menu()
{
    do
    {   
        system("cls");
        cout << "Input a point." << endl;
        cout << "id: " << endl;
        cout << "x: " << endl;
        cout << "y: " << endl<<;
        cout << "r: - Return." << endl; 

        system("pause");
    } while (true);

}

int main()
{   
    menu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? Doesn't system require #include <cstdlib> ?

Comment: @J99, Yeah, but headers can include other headers, so it might be from that.

Comment: Replace that `system` call with `cin.get();` and it should work.

Comment: @Griwes, it didn't help. The same error is here to stay. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!140&authkey=!AG3aeywh77TdOSA

Comment: @pepperwork Your problem is with this line: `cout << "y: " << endl<<;` , remove the extra << at the end and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. The problem is solved. But the screen blinks about 3 times a second now. It is clearly visible and is really irritating. Could you suggest me anything here?

Comment: @Pepperwork I don't get that behavior when I compile and run your code. It displays the lines on my console and then waits for me to press a key, and then repeats the whole thing when I do so (since you've placed it in an infinite loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some consoles use buffered output. That means thst you don't see any output until the buffer is full or a newline is written. Append \n to the string or add `<< endl` after the string.

Comment: Newline flush only happens in C, not in C++; also, standard C++ streams flush themselves in destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You don't flush `cout`. So the output is just sitting in the buffer when you do [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). Try:

```
cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
```

You write:

> It starts compiling but the result is just a flash of black screen.

That sounds good. Now try running the program from a console (since it's a console program).

Comment: No, this doesn't help. The reaction is the same.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `std::endl` prints a new line then flushes the stream, which is why David suggests it.

Comment: Standard streams flush themselves in destructor.

Comment: @Griwes: That doesn't help him, since he's expecting to see the output while his program is paused, before the destructor gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why there is a << after endl in the 4th cout statement in the menu() function...could that be the error?